# Cannot setup WebpackDevMiddleware on windows

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I've been banging my head against this issue all day now and still can't figure it out. This is the error I am getting

```
project\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\context.js:95
  context.compiler.hooks.invalid.tap('WebpackDevMiddleware', invalid);
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined
```

So something to do with my webpack dev middleware.

I've checked that the webpack on it's own is fine which or the sake of space I'll [leave a gist to.](https://gist.github.com/jackdh/f923fa1bd68d1993fd3d7e1f5d4d2004)

However when I try and launch it within the following Node / Express file I get the above error.

```
const env = require("node-env-file");
const envLocation = __dirname + "/../.env";
env(envLocation);

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const config = require('./../webpack.config.js')({env : "dev"});

const app = express();

if (process.env.ENV === "DEV") {
    const compiler = webpack(config);
    const middleware = webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
        contentBase: 'src',
        stats: {
            colors: true,
            hash: false,
            timings: true,
            chunks: false,
            chunkModules: false,
            modules: false
        }
    });

    app.use(middleware);
} else {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

    app.get('*', function response(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
    });
}


// Set Port, hosting services will look for process.env.PORT
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

// start the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${app.get('port')}`);
});
```

Can anyone see if I'm missing something obvious? I'm running this on a windows 10 machine.

`package.json`

```
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
"file-loader": "1.1.6",
"html-loader": "0.5.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
"node-sass": "4.7.2",
"rimraf": "2.6.2",
"sass-loader": "6.0.6",
"source-list-map": "2.0.0",
"style-loader": "0.20.1",
"uglify-js": "3.3.9",
"url-loader": "0.6.2",
"webpack": "3.10.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.0.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.11.1"
```

Comment: Either upgrade your Webpack or downgrade middleware, should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to webpack 4. worked for me.